# Установка цвета меню

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, мне надо сделать, чтоб меню было синего цвета, но у меня не получается, я нашел на одном сайте вот такой скрипт:

```
<div id="ss" style="width:140px; height:90px; background:url(путь к картинке) repeat-x;">Меню</div>
```

и он не сработал, менял размеры - всё равно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: в background правильный url к своей **синей** картинке прописываете?

background: blue; - пробовали?

Comment: нет, щяс попробую))

Comment: а есть код для стилей?

Comment: background: blue; это и есть код для стилей блока :)

Вместо background:url(путь к картинке) repeat-x;

Comment: Советую почаще заглядывать на http://htmlbook.ru . А если немного владеешь английским - пройди курсы на http://www.w3schools.com , там все просто и понятно объясняется.

Comment: @Саша Осипов Заголовок темы должен отражать сущность вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт? Вам надо в этом "скрипте", указать (путь к картинке) или же вместо `background:url(путь к картинке)` использовать `background-color: blue`.

Comment: Как же я не додумался, точно, спасибо!